# Reverting a URL in Flask to the endpoint + arguments

Tags: python, flask

What would be the appropriate way of resolving a URL within Flask to retrieve a reference to the endpoint as well as a dictionary of all the arguments?

To provide an example, given this route, I'd like to resolve `'/user/nick'` to `profile`,`{'username': 'nick'}`:

```py
@app.route('/user/<username>')
def profile(username): pass
```

From my research so far, all routes in Flask are stored under `app.url_map`. The map is an instance of [werkzeug.routing.Map](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/#werkzeug.routing.Map) and it has a method `match()` that would in principle do what I am looking for. However, that method is internal to the class.

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? This sort of thing is typically handled by Flask itself (which uses the Map's `match()` method, as you suggested). Why would you need to do something that Flask already does?

Comment: @MarkHildreth: one use of this is in RESTful APIs, when you get a resource URL as an argument and you need to decode it back into endpoint and arguments.

Comment: That's exactly my scenario. I am building a REST service.

Comment: @Miguel Same use case here. Thanks for the question and for the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is what I hacked for this purpose looking at `url_for()` and reversing it:

```
from flask.globals import _app_ctx_stack, _request_ctx_stack
from werkzeug.urls import url_parse

def route_from(url, method = None):
    appctx = _app_ctx_stack.top
    reqctx = _request_ctx_stack.top
    if appctx is None:
        raise RuntimeError('Attempted to match a URL without the '
                           'application context being pushed. This has to be '
                           'executed when application context is available.')

    if reqctx is not None:
        url_adapter = reqctx.url_adapter
    else:
        url_adapter = appctx.url_adapter
        if url_adapter is None:
            raise RuntimeError('Application was not able to create a URL '
                               'adapter for request independent URL matching. '
                               'You might be able to fix this by setting '
                               'the SERVER_NAME config variable.')
    parsed_url = url_parse(url)
    if parsed_url.netloc is not "" and parsed_url.netloc != url_adapter.server_name:
        raise NotFound()
    return url_adapter.match(parsed_url.path, method)
```

The return value of this method is a tuple, with the first element being the endpoint name and the second a dictionary with the arguments.

I haven't tested it extensively, but it worked for me in all cases.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I wanted correct handling of subdomains as well, and it turned out I had to construct a new request and URL adapter for that, so I've presented a new answer with this implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I know I am coming in late with an answer, but I ran into the same problem and found a simpler way to get it: `request.view_args`. For example:

In my views:

```
@app.route('/user/<username>')
def profile(username): 
    return render_template("profile.html")
```

In `profile.html`:
    {{request.view_args}}

When visiting the url `http://localhost:4999/user/sam`, I get: `{'username': u'sam'}`.

You can also get the name of the function that got your view with `request.endpoint`.

Comment: Hi Sam, my question was about getting the endpoint of an arbitrary URL, not necessarily the one that is currently being visited.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote Miguel's implementation to support subdomains:

```
from flask import current_app, request
from six.moves.urllib.parse import urlsplit

def endpoint_for(url, method=None, return_rule=False, follow_redirects=True):
    """
    Given an absolute URL, retrieve the matching endpoint name (or rule).
    Requires a current request context to determine runtime environment.

    :param str method: HTTP method to use (defaults to GET)
    :param bool return_rule: Return the URL rule instead of the endpoint name
    :param bool follow_redirects: Follow redirects to final endpoint
    :return: Endpoint name or URL rule, or `None` if not found
    """
    parsed_url = urlsplit(url)
    if not parsed_url.netloc:
        # We require an absolute URL
        return

    # Take the current runtime environment...
    environ = dict(request.environ)
    # ...but replace the HTTP host with the URL's host...
    environ['HTTP_HOST'] = parsed_url.netloc
    # ...and the path with the URL's path (after discounting the app path, if not hosted at root).
    environ['PATH_INFO'] = parsed_url.path[len(environ['SCRIPT_NAME']):]
    # Create a new request with this environment...
    url_request = current_app.request_class(environ)
    # ...and a URL adapter with the new request.
    url_adapter = current_app.create_url_adapter(url_request)

    # Domain or subdomain must match.
    # TODO: To support apps that host multiple domains, we need to remove this
    # check, or offer a callback hook to check the domain.
    if parsed_url.netloc != url_adapter.server_name and not (
            parsed_url.netloc.endswith('.' + url_adapter.server_name)):
        return

    try:
        endpoint_or_rule, view_args = url_adapter.match(parsed_url.path, method, return_rule=return_rule)
        return endpoint_or_rule
    except RequestRedirect as r:
        # A redirect typically implies `/folder` -> `/folder/`
        # This will not be a redirect response from a view, since the view isn't being called
        if follow_redirects:
            return endpoint_for(r.new_url, method=method, return_rule=return_rule, follow_redirects=follow_redirects)
    except HTTPException as e:
        pass
    # If we got here, no endpoint was found.
```