# How to not add prefix to invalid route path

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I'm working on a Flask GAE app and planning to support multiple languages with flask-babel.

I'm prefixing all route paths with a two-letter language code, and I have redirects set up to enforce it. Assuming English is the user's preference of the languages I support, I have it set up so `/` redirects to `/en/`, and `/about` redirects to `/en/about/`, for example.

My issue is that this leads to invalid routes getting redirected before they 404. For example, `/dsdf` redirects to `/en/dsdf/` and then 404s. I would rather just have the plain URL 404 without a redirect. I don't know how to check if a given path, missing a prefix, would correspond to a valid route if it had a prefix.

Here's a minimum code sample of my `main.py`. The only information I could find online about this was https://medium.com/@nicolas_84494/flask-create-a-multilingual-web-application-with-language-specific-urls-5d994344f5fd, and things didn't seem to work the same way for me; `request.url_rule.defaults` evaluated to `None`.

```
from flask import Flask, g, request
from flask_babel import Babel

SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES = ['en', 'es', 'zh']

app = Flask(__name__)
babel = Babel(app)

@babel.localeselector
def get_locale():
    if not g.get('lang', None) or g.lang not in SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES:
        g.lang = request.accept_languages.best_match(SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES)
    return g.lang

@app.url_value_preprocessor
def pull_lang_code(endpoint, values):
    if values is None:
        values = {}
    g.lang = values.pop('lang', None)

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    prefix = request.full_path.split('/')[1].rstrip('/ ?')
    if prefix not in SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES:
        # handle URLs that aren't properly prefixed with a langauge
        return redirect('/' + get_locale() + request.full_path, 302)

@app.route('/<lang>/')
def index():
    return 'Hello, world! ' + g.lang

@app.route('/<lang>/about/')
def about():
    return 'About ' + g.lang

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I sorted out how to check the validity of a path without using a test client, using [this answer from another question about how to look up the route for a given path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19637175/2752467).

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    path = request.full_path
    prefix = path.split('/')[1].rstrip('/ ?')
    if prefix not in SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES:
        prefixed_path = '/' + get_locale() + path
        route_from(prefixed_path)
        return redirect(prefixed_path, 302)

def route_from(url, method = None):
    appctx = _app_ctx_stack.top
    reqctx = _request_ctx_stack.top
    if appctx is None:
        raise RuntimeError('Attempted to match a URL without the '
                           'application context being pushed. This has to be '
                           'executed when application context is available.')

    if reqctx is not None:
        url_adapter = reqctx.url_adapter
    else:
        url_adapter = appctx.url_adapter
        if url_adapter is None:
            raise RuntimeError('Application was not able to create a URL '
                               'adapter for request independent URL matching. '
                               'You might be able to fix this by setting '
                               'the SERVER_NAME config variable.')
    parsed_url = url_parse(url)
    if parsed_url.netloc is not "" and parsed_url.netloc != url_adapter.server_name:
        raise NotFound()
    return url_adapter.match(parsed_url.path, method)
```

I don't assign the return value for `route_from` because I'm just calling it so that `raise NotFound` can trigger on an invalid path. It could probably be stripped down into a much simpler function but I don't have time at the moment.

Now `before_request` does nothing for complete valid paths, redirects paths that are missing a language prefix but otherwise valid, and 404s without a redirect for paths that are totally invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue is with your before_request callback. You make your return a redirect without checking the url provided in the request, so flask formulates the redirect url and then tries to redirect the user to it, which then ends in a 404 when it discovers that the url doesnt exist.

```
    if prefix not in SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES:
        # handle URLs that aren't properly prefixed with a langauge
        return redirect('/' + get_locale() + request.full_path, 302)
```

I would first write code that checks the url provided in the request to make sure it is valid. Redirect if it is valid otherwise abort(404).

Hope that gives you an idea of how to solve the problem.

---

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28861440/is-it-possible-to-check-if-a-url-sent-to-flask-will-404.) for reference.

```
    if prefix not in SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES:
        url = request.full_path
        if is_path_valid(url):
            return redirect('/' + get_locale() + url, 302
        abort(404)
```

The definition of `is_path_valid()`:

```
def is_path_valid(url):
    with app.test_client() as client:
        response = client.get(url)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: "I would first write code that checks the url provided in the request to make sure it is valid." How do I do that? That's basically what my question is. I'll update to be clearer.

Comment: With this solution, I get an error `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` when trying to access URLs without prefixes (regardless of if they're valid or not). I'm not familiar with how `test_client()` works in Flask, but from the stack trace I'm guessing that the instantiation of test client involves triggering these callbacks, causing an infinite recursion loop.